# Scraping Youtube Recommendations with Beautifulsoup: Do results have a personalization bent?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, youtube, personalization

YouTube's "recommended videos" are based on viewing history (i.e. personalization), either from cookies or account history.

When scraping recommended videos using beautifulsoup, is there any personalization?

Note: the beautifulsoup "recommended videos" do not match my own when I manually search, suggesting that my own personalization does not affect the results. But does some other personalization affect the results?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


goto = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
body = urllib.request.urlopen(goto)
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, from_encoding=body.info().get_param('charset'))
recommended_urls =[]
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if "/watch?" in link['href']:
        recommended_urls.append(link['href'])
list(set(recommended_urls))
```

Comment: As you've guessed, there is no personilizationdata since the request doesn't have any cookies. The page should have videos YouTube recommends to unregistered users by default.